# Why is 13.10 delivered with java 6 instead of java 7?

Tags: package-management

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 from scratch and I'm surprised that it installed java 6 (openjdk-6-jre) instead of java 7 (openjdk-7-jre).

What is the reason behind this choice?

Comment: Can you install aptitude and run `aptitude why openjdk-6-jre`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, lets analyze the dependencies of the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` packages:

```
apt-cache depends ubuntu-restricted-extras
ubuntu-restricted-extras
  Depends: ubuntu-restricted-addons
  Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer
  Recommends: unrar
  Recommends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse
  Recommends: libavcodec-extra-53
  Conflicts: ubuntu-restricted-extras:i386
```

Here, isn't java, lets analize depper the dependencies of `ubuntu-restricted-addons`:

```
apt-cache depends ubuntu-restricted-addons
ubuntu-restricted-addons
  Recommends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
  Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
  Recommends: flashplugin-installer
    flashplugin-installer:i386
  Recommends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
  Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
  Recommends: gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
  Recommends: gstreamer1.0-libav
  Recommends: gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3
  Conflicts: ubuntu-restricted-addons:i386
```

Nope, ubuntu-restricted-extras do not install java. Actually, only could ever install it in a very roundabout manner.

```
$ aptitude why ubuntu-restricted-extras default-jdk
p   ubuntu-restricted-extras  Recommends ttf-mscorefonts-installer               
i A ttf-mscorefonts-installer Depends    update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2)
i A update-notifier-common    Depends    debconf                                 
i   debconf                   Suggests   debconf-doc                             
p   debconf-doc               Suggests   debian-policy (>= 3.5)                  
p   debian-policy             Suggests   doc-base                                
i A doc-base                  Suggests   rarian-compat                           
p   rarian-compat             Depends    docbook-xml                             
p   docbook-xml               Suggests   docbook-xsl                             
p   docbook-xsl               Suggests   libsaxon-java                           
p   libsaxon-java             Suggests   libsaxon-java-doc                       
p   libsaxon-java-doc         Recommends default-jdk-doc                         
p   default-jdk-doc           Suggests   default-jdk                             
$ aptitude why ubuntu-restricted-extras default-jre
p   ubuntu-restricted-extras  Recommends ttf-mscorefonts-installer               
i A ttf-mscorefonts-installer Depends    update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2)
i A update-notifier-common    Depends    debconf                                 
i   debconf                   Suggests   debconf-doc                             
p   debconf-doc               Suggests   debian-policy (>= 3.5)                  
p   debian-policy             Suggests   doc-base                                
i A doc-base                  Suggests   rarian-compat                           
p   rarian-compat             Depends    docbook-xml                             
p   docbook-xml               Suggests   docbook-xsl                             
p   docbook-xsl               Suggests   libxalan2-java                          
p   libxalan2-java            Suggests   libxsltc-java                           
p   libxsltc-java             Depends    jlex                                    
p   jlex                      Depends    default-jre             
$ aptitude why ubuntu-restricted-extras icedtea-plugin
p   ubuntu-restricted-extras  Recommends ttf-mscorefonts-installer                                              
i A ttf-mscorefonts-installer PreDepends dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2)                                                     
i   dpkg                      Suggests   apt                                                                    
i   apt                       Suggests   aptitude | synaptic | wajig                                            
p   wajig                     Suggests   reportbug                                                              
i A reportbug                 Suggests   claws-mail (>= 3.8.0)                                                  
p   claws-mail                Depends    libenchant1c2a (>= 1.6)                                                
i A libenchant1c2a            Depends    aspell-en | myspell-dictionary | aspell-dictionary | ispell-dictionary 
                                         | hunspell-dictionary                                                  
p   myspell-uk                Provides   myspell-dictionary                                                     
p   myspell-uk                Suggests   libreoffice                                                            
p   libreoffice               Suggests   default-jre | gcj-jre | java-gcj-compat | openjdk-6-jre | openjdk-7-jre
                                          | sun-java5-jre | sun-java6-jre | java5-runtime | jre                 
p   openjdk-6-jre             Suggests   icedtea-plugin
```

So, unless you give more information ubuntu packages doesn't install java unless you manually specify it.

Comment: I did not install java 6 manually. It was installed by the Ubuntu 13.10 installer.

Comment: Can you provide the name of the package? like `dpkg -l package`?